# Getting wrong values from form after submitting

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, forms

After submitting form database getting wrong values. So the form is working like this: user chooses username from the selection options and then system is getting chosen user's id(using ajax) in non-editable field. After user choose department and pressing submit. Data is storing in database but I got a problem with values, cuz id is becoming username and username just disappears, and id is becoming 0. Cant understand what is the problem. Here is HTML code of the form:

```
<form id="reguserform" method="post" action="register.php#err">
    <?php
        $res = verifyFormFields();
    ?>
    <!-- Username field -->
    <select class="empidselectbox" name="username" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
        <option disabled selected>Username (required)</option>
        <?php
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo "<option value='".$row[1]."'>$row[0]</option>";
            }
            mysql_free_result($result);
        ?>
    </select>

    <!-- Id field -->
    <input type="hidden" name="ID" />
    <div id="txtHint"><input type="text" class="input name" name="ID" placeholder="ID" disabled="disabled"/></div> 

    <!-- Employee group field -->
    <select class="empidselectbox" name="userGroup">
        <option disabled selected>User group (required)</option>
        <option value = "Planning Department" >Planning Department</option>
        <option value="HR Department">HR Department</option>
        <option value="Recruitment Department">Recruitment Department</option>
    </select>

    <center><input type="submit" class="button small" name="submit" value="Register User"/></center>

    <?php   
        if($count == 1) 
        {                               
            if($res=="")
            { 
                registerUser();
                echo"<script>document.getElementById('testRegister').innerHTML=registerStr;callShowAlert();</script>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<a style='color:red';>$res</a>";
            }
        }
    ?>
</form>
```

Then come verification part which checks if user already in database and after that generating password and adding to the database:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){    
    if (isset($_POST["username"])) {$username = $_POST["username"];}
    if (isset($_POST["uid"])) {$ID = $_POST["uid"];}
    if (isset($_POST["userGroup"])) {$userGroup = $_POST["userGroup"];}

    $count = 1;
}
else $count = 0;

function registerUser(){
    global $username,$ID,$userGroup;
    // To protect MySQL injection
    $username = cleanInputData($username);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);

    $email = $username . "@pk.com";
    $result = getStatus($userGroup);

    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $roleID = $row[0];
    }
    $random_string_length = 6;
    $characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    $password = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $random_string_length; $i++) {
        $password .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }

    //query result
    $result = insertNewUser($username,md5($password),$ID,$email,$roleID,1);
    // Check result
    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid queryyyy: ' . mysql_error());
    }   
 }

function verifyFormFields(){
    global $username,$ID,$userGroup;

    if(isset($username))
    {
        $result = getUser($username);

        if (!$result) {
            die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
            return "<p id ='err'>This Username Already Exists!</p>";
        }
    }

    if(empty($username)){
        return "<p id ='err'>Please Select Username</p>";
    }
    else if(empty($userGroup)){
        return "<p id ='err'>Please Select User Group</p>"; 
    }

    else return "";
}
?>
```

And the functions I am using to get the data and insert it to a table:

```
<?php
    function getUnregisteredEmployee()
    {
        global $con;
        $sql = "SELECT username, uid FROM `user`";
        return @mysql_query($sql,$con);
    }

    function getID()
    {
        global $con;
        $q = intval($_GET['q']);
        $sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid = '".$q."'";
        return @mysql_query($sql,$con);
    }

    function getUser($username){
        global $con;
        $sql = "SELECT username
        FROM `user` WHERE username='$username'";
        return @mysql_query($sql,$con);
    }

    function getStatus($status){
        global $con;    
        $sql = "SELECT roleID FROM `user_group` WHERE `status` = '$status'";
        return @mysql_query($sql,$con);
    }

    function insertNewUser($username,$password,$ID,$email,$role,$active){
        global $con;    
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `user_dep`(`username`,`password`,`empID`,`email`,`role`,`active`)
        VALUES ('$username', '$password','$ID', '$email','$role','$active');";
        return @mysql_query($sql,$con);
    }
?>
```

And ajax part which appears after user choose username:

```
$result = getID();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='ID' />";
    echo "<input type='text' class='input name'  name='ID'  value='".$row['uid']."' name='username' disabled='disabled'/>";

}

?>
```

Comment: You are using ID as readonly, and they are not posted in form. Use disabled instead.

Comment: @user1885057 I used disabled and added hidden input to get value from form, however still got this problem

Comment: Do you figure out with this?